# Tesseract options & image preprocessing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ocr, tesseract, image-preprocessing

[The image I try to OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87c3C.jpg)

[Edit : As asked, here is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJtgY.jpg)

Dear community
I am trying to do some ocr.
I have already pre-processed the image a lot (unskew, crop...)
Now, I can read the digits myself with no problem
But I can't get tesseract giving me a meaningfull result.

Click on the link at the top to see the image I am trying to OCR

Is there more pre-processing I am missing ?
Or do I call tesseract badly ?

I tried with no option at all, or with that :

```
config = ('--psm 13 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

***Edit :***

*Funny thing, I tried multiple ways :*

- Tesseract 5 on Windows, give nothing **'eT'**   (but maybe bad
  config)
- Google API from Phyton Jupyter Notebook on Windows => **'UO0
  1124'** or something like that don't quite remember
- Tesseract 4 on buntu with config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 13') : **'WU000 244m'**
- Google API from Python Jpyter Notebook on Ubuntu => **'U000241\n'**

So It's the very beggining for me. 
Imay prefere to use Tesseract so as not to pay big bucks. 
Will se what I can do when my project is more advanced.

But I am eager to hear your suggestions about image preprocessing !! :-)

So if you have suggestion.

Regards !

Comment: Is posted image original or preprocessed? If preprocessed then please post original.

Answer (score 11):

You can give three important flags for tesseract to work and these are `-l` , `--oem` , and `--psm`.

- The `-l`  flag controls the language of the input text.
- The `--oem`  argument, or OCR Engine Mode, controls the type of algorithm used by Tesseract.
- The `--psm`  controls the automatic Page Segmentation Mode used by Tesseract.

to get options use:

- `tesseract --help-oem` for oem.
- `tesseract --help-psm` for psm.
- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files for language codes:

use these options like this `config = ("-l eng --oem 1 --psm 7")`

Comment: `tesseract --help-oem` and `tesseract --help-psm`. Great! For anyone who wants to read more https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/